# What is differences between category and extensions in objective-c i am confused any good articles for that..>?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Hi i am confused with category and extensions in objective-c  any good articles for that

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Just](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) [a](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#categories) [few](http://maniacdev.com/2009/04/what-are-objective-c-categories/) [examples](http://thaesofereode.info/clocFAQ/#categories)

Answer (score 3):

I find Apple's documentation quite good: http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html

Comment: http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html
this is good for category